# Call to undefined method CakeResponse::file()

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I want to download a file after a request is completed I am using this method
public function sendFile($id) {

```
$this->response->file($id, array('download' => true, 'name' => 'PostNet'));
//Return reponse object to prevent controller from trying to render a view
return $this->response;
}
```

But I get an error like  Call to undefined method CakeResponse::file() . Should I include any class or CakeResponse or it's included already?
Thanks

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're working CakePHP version doesn't suppose `$this->response->file()` method. If so then you need to use *[CakePHP Media View](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html)* for download file.

***NOTE:***

For `$this->response->file()` the first parameter is a complete `PATH` to file location. For example:

```
$this->response->file(
                      WWW_ROOT.'files/'. 'somename.ext', // FULL PATH to file
                      array('download' => true, 'name' => 'SomeName')
                  );
```

Nothing to include additionally for `CakeResponse::file()`.